# Insert new method call in InvocatioExpression

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am writing a visual studio code fix with provider which will insert `AsEnumerable` call inside this kind of statement:

```
model.clients.Take(10).Select(c => new Client(c));
```

I am able to detect such statements but have issues inserting the `AsEnumerable` before `Select` method. This is what I have tried:

```
        var expressionSyntax = SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression(".AsEnumerable()");
        var memberAccessExpressionSyntax = invocationExpr.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;

        var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);

        var newRoot = root.InsertNodesAfter(memberAccessExpressionSyntax.Expression, new[] {expressionSyntax});

        return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
```

but I get

> "System.InvalidOperationException: The item specified is not the
>   element of a list."

See stacktrace at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/02c41f232829163b25ae

What is a proper way to call `InsertNodesAfter` method?

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks Added to question.

Comment: `InsertNodesAfter` only works for nodes in a list.  Method calls are not a list; you need to splice in a new call expression.

Comment: @SLaks: How do I do that?

Comment: where exactly do you want to insert the call?

Comment: @user2697817 Why did you delete your answer? It helped me.

Comment: I realised I'd made an error and didn't want to mislead you. I didn't have time to correct it. I'll try and do it now.

Comment: @user2697817: Yes, there was an error but it pushed me in a right direction. See me answer below.

Comment: Just seen, glad you managed to solve it. I see you replaced the expression on the memberAccess first which is where I went wrong.

Comment: @user2697817: Yes, but you deserve an up-vote too

Comment: Haha. Never mind :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
var memberAccessExpressionSyntax = invocationExpr.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;

var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);

var accessExpression = SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression, memberAccessExpressionSyntax.Expression, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("AsEnumerable"));

var invocationExpression = SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(accessExpression);
var enumerableMemberAccessExpression = memberAccessExpressionSyntax.WithExpression(invocationExpression);

root = root.ReplaceNode(invocationExpr, invocationExpr.WithExpression(enumerableMemberAccessExpression));
```

Answer (score 0):

`InsertNodesAfter` only works for nodes in a list.  Method calls are not a list, but rather a tree of call expressions.

You need to replace the expression in the `XXX.Select(...)` call with `XXX.AsEnumerable()` (reusing the same `XXX` node).

To understand how these expression trees work, use the Roslyn Syntax Visualizer.

Comment: The problem is that there can be variable number of method calls before Select method is called so I don't want to have to reconstruct all of them and append AsEnumerable.

Comment: You don't have to reconstruct all of them. Find the one where you want to insert it, and then you'll replace the call of x.Foo() with x.Bar().Foo(). Perhaps the best way to think about it is if you add a bunch of extra parens: x.Foo() can be thought of as (x).Foo(), and you can replace that inner thing with (x.Bar()).Foo().